# Multiple movieclips all go to the same spot; What am i doing wrong?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, projectile

So I'm trying to shoot multiple bullets out of my body and it all works except I have an odd problem of just one bullet showing up and updating to set position for the new ones.
I have a move able player thats supposed to shoot and I test this code by moving the player and shooting. Im taking it step by step in creating this.

The result of tracing the bulletContainer counts correctly in that its telling me that movieclips ARE being added to the stage; I Just know it comes down to some kind of logic that im forgetting.

**Here's My Code** (The Bullet it self is a class)

**UPDATE***
Everything in this code works fine except for I stated earlier some code seems reduntned because I've resorted to a different approaches.

**BulletGod Class:**

```
public class bulletGod extends MovieClip{
    //Register Variables
        //~Global
            var globalPath                      = "http://127.0.0.1/fleshvirusv3/serverside/"

        //~MovieCLips
            var newBullet:bulletClass           = new bulletClass();

        //~Boolean
            var loadingBulletInProgress:Number  = 0;
            var shootingWeapon:Number           = 0;

        //~Timers
            var fireBulletsInterval     = setInterval(fireBullets, 1);
            var bulletFireEvent;

        //~Arrays
            var bulletArray:Array               = new Array();
            var bulletType:Array                = new Array();
            var bulletContainer:Array           = new Array();

        //~Networking
            var netBulletRequest:URLRequest     = new URLRequest(globalPath+"bullets.php");
            var netBulletVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            var netBulletLoader:URLLoader       = new URLLoader();          

        //~Bullet Image Loader
            var mLoader:Loader                  = new Loader();
            var mRequest:URLRequest             = new URLRequest();

                public function bulletGod() {
                    //Load every bullet for every gun

                    //Compile data to be requested
                         netBulletVariables.act             = "loadBullets"
                         netBulletRequest.method            = URLRequestMethod.POST
                         netBulletRequest.data              = netBulletVariables;
                         netBulletLoader.dataFormat         = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

                         netBulletLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getBulletImages);
                         netBulletLoader.load(netBulletRequest);

                }

                private function getBulletImages(bulletImageData:Event){
                    //Request every bullet URL image

                    //Set vars
                    var bulletData = bulletImageData.target.data;

                    //Load images
                    for(var i:Number = 0; i < bulletData.numBullets; i++){
                        bulletArray.push(bulletData["id"+i.toString()]);
                        bulletType.push(bulletData["bullet"+i.toString()]);
                        //trace(bulletData["id"+i]+"-"+bulletData["bullet"+i]);
                    }

                    //All the arrays have been set start firing the image loader/replacer
                    var imageLoaderInterval = setInterval(imageReplacer, 10);

                }

                private function imageReplacer(){
                    //Check to see which image needs replacing
                    if(!loadingBulletInProgress){
                        //Begin loading the next image
                            //Search for the next "String" in the bulletType:Array, and replace it with an image
                            for(var i:Number = 0; i < bulletType.length; i++){
                                if(getQualifiedClassName(bulletType[i]) == "String"){
                                    //Load this image
                                        mRequest = new URLRequest(globalPath+"ammo/"+bulletType[i]);
                                        mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImage);
                                        mLoader.load(mRequest);

                                        //Stop imageReplacer() while we load image
                                        loadingBulletInProgress = 1;

                                        //Stop this for() loop while we load image
                                        i = 999;
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }

                private function loadImage(BlackHole:Event){
                    //Image has loaded; find which array slot it needs to go into

                    for(var i:Number = 0; i <= bulletType.length; i++){
                        if(getQualifiedClassName(bulletType[i]) == "String"){
                            //We found which array type it belongs to; now replace the text/url location with the actual image data
                            var tmpNewBullet:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
                                tmpNewBullet.addChild(mLoader);

                            //Add image to array
                                bulletType[i] = tmpNewBullet;

                            //Restart loadingBullets if there are more left
                                loadingBulletInProgress = 0;

                            //Stop for() loop
                            i = 999;
                        }
                    }
                }
//###############################################################################################################################################
            private function fireBullets(){
                //If player is holding down mouse; Fire weapon at rate of fire.
                if(shootingWeapon >= 1){
                    if(bulletFireEvent == null){
                        //Start shooting bullets
                        bulletFireEvent = setInterval(allowShooting, 500);
                    }
                }

                if(shootingWeapon == 0){
                    //The user is not shooting so stop all bullets from firing
                    if(bulletFireEvent != null){
                        //Strop firing bullets
                        clearInterval(bulletFireEvent);
                        bulletFireEvent = null
                    }
                }
            }

            private function allowShooting(){
                //This function actually adds the bullets on screen

                //Search for correct bullet/ammo image to attach
                    var bulletId:Number = 0;
                    for(var i:Number = 0; i < bulletArray.length; i++){
                        if(bulletArray[i] == shootingWeapon){
                            //Bullet found
                            bulletId = i;

                            //End For() loop
                            i = 999;
                        }
                    }

                //Create new bullet
                        //Create Tmp Bullet
                        var tmpBulletId:MovieClip = new MovieClip
                            tmpBulletId.addChild(newBullet);
                            tmpBulletId.addChild(bulletType[bulletId]);
                        //Add To Stage
                            addChild(tmpBulletId)
                            bulletContainer.push(tmpBulletId);  //Add to array of bullets

                //Orientate this bullet from players body
                        var bulletTmpId:Number = bulletContainer.length
                            bulletTmpId--;
                            bulletContainer[bulletTmpId].x = Object(root).localSurvivor.x
                            bulletContainer[bulletTmpId].y = Object(root).localSurvivor.y

                            //addChild(bulletContainer[bulletTmpId]);   
            }


            //_______________EXTERNAL EVENTS_______________________
                public function fireBullet(weaponId:Number){
                    shootingWeapon = weaponId;
                }

                public function stopFireBullets(){
                    shootingWeapon = 0;
                }
    }

}
```

**BulletClass:**

```
package  com{
        import flash.display.*
        import flash.utils.*
        import flash.net.*
        import flash.events.*
    public class bulletClass extends MovieClip {
            public var damage:Number = 0;

        public function bulletClass() {
            //SOME MOVEMENT CODE HERE
        }

        public function addAvatar(Obj:MovieClip){
            this.addChild(Obj);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to tell us where this code is executed, is it in the document class? Is "this" referring to the stage? Why are you adding the newBullet object to the tmpBulletId MovieClip?

Comment: Also, need to know what's in bulletClass. Maybe it shares its children with other bulletClasses?

Comment: Thanks for your input guys! Heres the setup.. I have the main stage which intitates the "bulletGod" class onto the main stage.  Inside the bulletGod: It requests bullet images from the server attaches it to an associated array with an id#(so the bullet will match with the dynamically loaded gun). Then i have a function that loops every 100ms and if the player is shooting it will spit out bullets(were we are at right now)

Comment: And what exactly is the result? How many bullets and where are they? How can this line: tmpNewBullet.addChild(mLoader); work?

Answer (score 1):

Well ... if I may say so, this code looks quite wrong. Either something is missing from the code or this code will never make the bullets fly.

First off, you can set x and y of the new bullet directly (replace everything after "orientate this bullet from players body" with this):

```
tmpBulletId.x = Object(root).localSurvivor.x;
tmpBulletId.y = Object(root).localSurvivor.y;
```

Perhaps this already helps, but your code there should already do the same.

But to let these bullets fly into any direction, you also need to add an event listener, like so:

```
tmpBulletId.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBullet);

function moveBullet(e:Event) {
    var movedBullet:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
    if (movedBullet.x < 0 || movedBullet.x > movedBullet.stage.width || 
        movedBullet.y < 0 || movedBullet.y > movedBullet.stage.height) {

        // remove move listener, because the bullet moved out of stage
        movedBullet.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME);
    }
    // remove the comment (the //) from the line that you need
    MovieClip(e.currentTarget).x += 1; // move right
    // MovieClip(e.currentTarget).y -= 1; // move up
    // MovieClip(e.currentTarget).x -= 1; // move left
    // MovieClip(e.currentTarget).y += 1; // move down
}
```

This example lets your bullet fly to the right. If you need it flying into another direction, just comment out the line with the "move right" comment and uncomment one of the other lines.

This is of course a very simple example, but it should get you started.

I hope this helps, and that my answer is not the wrong answer to the question.

Comment: Thank your for your input but the bullet class moves it self once initiated all i have to do is input the rotation and off it goes but either way i only posted up the important parts that was related to the question for understanding.

Comment: Ah ok, now I see you posted your original code. well, ok, I can't see the error in there either. If you make your bullet movement code in your bulletClass and only update the position of the bulletClass instance with using "this", then it should work. Otherwise I have no idea what may be wrong, because the placement of the bullet is basically right.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have expirienced it you can have only one copy of MovieClip object added to specific child. Best approach is to use ByteArray for the clip source and instantiate new MovieClip and pass the ByteArray as a source. It have something to do with child/parent relation since a DisplayObject can have only one parent (and a way to detach the object from scene too).

Comment: He instantiates a new movieclip, so it's not the same movieclip being added. This doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well i ended up writeing the whole code from scratch for a 3rd time and ran into a similar problem and just for reference to anybody else that comes to a problem thats random as this one i found that problem was likly does to a conversion error somewhere that doesn't necessarily break any compiling rules. Just that i was calling a movieclip and not the class it self.